# Checking return address in recvfrom() (C UDP Sockets)

Tags: c

This pertains to attempting to validate the return address in recvfrom() (the fifth argument to the function) in this UDP echo client:

While I can send data to the server and receive return communications correctly, I'm having trouble validating the return IP address when comparing the fromAddr.sin_addr and echoServAddr.sin_addr.

The goal here is to compare the address in the structure that was used in sendto() and the address in the structure returned from recvfrom() to validate the echo reply from the server indeed came from where the initial transmission from the client was sent (A rudimentary POC that there wasn't a Man In The Middle).

*What should I be looking at in order to appropriately validate the return address as it is returned from recvfrom() matches the address transmitted to as referenced in the sendto() call?*

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket(), connect(), sendto(), and recvfrom() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in and inet_addr() */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() and exit() */
#include <string.h>     /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* for close() */

#define ECHOMAX 255     /* Longest string to echo */

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage);  /* External error handling function */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;                        /* Socket descriptor */
    struct sockaddr_in echoServAddr; /* Echo server address */
    struct sockaddr_in fromAddr;     /* Source address of echo */
    unsigned short echoServPort;     /* Echo server port */
    unsigned int fromSize;           /* In-out of address size for recvfrom() */
    char *servIP;                    /* IP address of server */
    char *echoString;                /* String to send to echo server */
    char echoBuffer[ECHOMAX+1];      /* Buffer for receiving echoed string */
    int echoStringLen;               /* Length of string to echo */
    int respStringLen;               /* Length of received response */

    // manage the command line arguments and errors
    if ((argc < 3) || (argc > 4)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <Server IP> <Echo Word> [<Echo Port>]\n",
            argv[0]);
        exit(1);
        }
    // load servIP
    servIP = argv[1];
    // load echoString
    echoString = argv[2];
    // check echoString and error if too long
    echoStringLen = strlen(echoString);
    if (!(echoStringLen <= 255)) {
        DieWithError("BUFFER EXCEEDED ERROR");
    }
    // load port
    if (argc == 4)
        echoServPort = atoi(argv[3]);
    else
        echoServPort = 7;
    // create the socket
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        DieWithError("SOCKET CREATION ERROR");
    }
        /* Construct the server address structure */
        memset(&echoServAddr, 0, sizeof(echoServAddr));    /* Zero out structure */
        echoServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                 /* Internet addr family */
        echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servIP);  /* Server IP address */
        echoServAddr.sin_port   = htons(echoServPort);     /* Server port */

    // send the string
    inet_pton(AF_INET, servIP, &echoServAddr.sin_addr);
    if ((sendto(sock, echoString, strlen(echoString), 0, (struct sockaddr *)
        &echoServAddr, sizeof(echoServAddr))) < 0) {
        DieWithError("SEND ERROR");
    }
    // recieve a response
    respStringLen = recvfrom(sock, echoBuffer, sizeof(echoBuffer), 0,
        (struct sockaddr *) &fromAddr, &fromSize);
    if (respStringLen < 0) {
        DieWithError("RECV ERROR");
    }
    // print the message sent
    printf("SENT FROM CLIENT: '%s'\n", echoString);
    // print the message recieved
    echoBuffer[respStringLen] = '\0';
    printf("RECEIVED FROM SERVER: '%s'\n", echoBuffer);
    // check if from the correct server
    if ((struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr.sin_addr != (struct sockaddr *) &fromAddr.sin_addr) {
        DieWithError("INVALID RETURN ADDRESS");
    }
    // close the socket
    close(sock);
    // exit the program
    exit(0);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  In the future, when posting code, after pasting it in, select it and click the `{}` widget, which will shift it right 4 spaces, causing it to be rendered as code.  Avoid tabs unless they're set to 4 spaces.

Comment: Note that (usually) the server will assign a 'ephemeral' port number for the communication, so you cannot depend on the port transmitted to in the server being the same as the port the server will use to transmit the echo.  Also, the client needs to allow for the server never receiving the packet and/or the client never receiving the response

Comment: Error handling for `recvfrom()` would definitely be a good next step and that is something that will be implemented in the future. As for the validation component, it was only necessary to validate the return IP address in this instance so there wouldn't be an issue with having a mismatch as the result of a client ephemeral port. Thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the source IP/port of the incoming packet is the same as the destation IP/port of the packet you sent, then the `sin_addr` and `sin_port` fields of `echoServAddr` and `fromAddr` should match.

This line of code however doesn't do that:

```
if ((struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr.sin_addr != (struct sockaddr *) &fromAddr.sin_addr) {
```

This is comparing the *address* of `echoServAddr.sin_addr` against the *address* of `fromAddr.sin_addr`.  Because these are two separate variables, this will always be false.  You instead want:

```
if ((echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr != fromAddr.sin_addr.s_addr) || 
    (echoServAddr.sin_port != fromAddr.sin_port))
```

Comment: Thank you this is the correct answer. It should also be noted that to affect a valid comparison that `unsigned int fromSize` needs to be set equal to `sizeof(fromAddr)` before the `recvfrom()` call.